# How can I Dual-Boot 2 internal SSD's (Win/Ubuntu) and have each able to run the other as a VM?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, python, ssd, virtualization

I have a new laptop on the way, it has 1TB SSD *2, 32GB RAM, i9 processor and 4080 GPU.
I want to set up dual boot - win/ubuntu each on their own SSD.
I also want each OS to be able to run the other as a VM.

**Q1** is this possible?
**Q2** is this safe?
**Q3** is this useful?

I have >30years PC use, primarily with AutoCAD.

Comment: Q2 is opinion based, Q3 is not answerable because we cant know how useful you think your idea is.

Comment: Possible yes. But you will need a common bootloader, that will offer you a selection which OS you want to start. So grub has to be installed on the "primary" disk, in order to offer you either Windows or Linux. Alternatively you'll have to change your boot order in UEFI every time you want to switch you OS.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Ubuntu operating system in a dual boot setup can run the other as a virtual machine. If you want to run two operating systems at the same time then one of the two operating systems must be installed as a guest operating system in a virtual machine. The same goes for a multiboot setup.

To run an operating system as a virtual machine, it must first be installed as a disk image. This disk image can then be loaded by a virtualization software, such as VirtualBox installed on the physical machine which creates a virtual computer environment (virtual machine) for the guest operating system to run in.

Comment: OK - I install grub to allow selection of the OS at boot - If I were to use Fedora instead of Ubuntu and use containers for the virtualisation, do I still need an image of each OS?

Comment: Also would there be any way to sync the OS image with the bootable install (ie. could I somehow have the bootable install of Fedora mirror itself to the image at shutdown and the same with windows and its image?

Comment: @SimonToft You would still need a disk image of each OS even if you were to use containers for virtualization. This is because containers are a lightweight virtualization technology that still requires an underlying operating system to run on. In a containerized environment, each container runs on a shared operating system kernel, but it has its own isolated filesystem, network namespace, and process space. This allows multiple containers to run on the same hardware without interfering with each other.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think the core of my query relates to persistence. If I boot into Win11 on C:\ then use a fedora image to modify an existing python project on d:\ will those changes persist when the image is shutdown? Or am I creating a 'fork' of the project to be saved separately?

Comment: @SimonToft No, the changes you make to the Python project on D:\ will not persist when the Fedora image is shut down. This is because containers are ephemeral by nature, which means that they are not designed to store data permanently. In order to persist changes to data, you need to mount a persistent volume to the container. A persistent volume is a storage device that is not specific to the container and that will survive the shutdown of the container. Further inquiries into containers should be asked as a separate question at Unix & Linux QA. I hope this helps.